# Can't insert Title of Category in HTML with Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, categories

I want to display only the title of my Django Category in HTML, but don't know how to access it properly. For the Category I use the MPTT library.
My views.py looks like this:

```
def category_products(request,id,slug):
    products = Product.objects.filter(category_id=id)
    category = Category.objects.all()
    context={'products': products,
             'category':category,
             'slug': slug}
    return render(request,'sondermuenz/category_products.html',context)
```

The model

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['title']

    def __str__(self):                           
        full_path = [self.title]            
        k = self.parent
        while k is not None:
            full_path.append(k.title)
            k = k.parent

        return ' -> '.join(full_path[::-1])

class Product(models.Model):
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(....)
    ...
```

The urls:

```
path('products_13/<int:id>/<slug:slug>', views.category_products, name='products'),
```

When I insert in my html file this

```
<h1>{{ slug }}</h1>
```

I can show the passed in slug, but how can I display the title of the product or category?
If I loop through it will show the same amount of titles as the looped objects, but I want to display it only once.
I hope someone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `{{ slug }}` you are rendering is coming from the context in your view:

```
 context={'products': products,
             'category':category,
             'slug': slug}
```

This is where you specify the names of objects that you want to render in the template. Right now, `categories` and `products` in your template will both be querysets, or a list of objects from the Django ORM. If you want to show just the first category title you could modify the context in the view:

```
context = {'first_category': Category.objects.first().name}
```

Then you could use `first_category` in the template. Or you can use Jinja's logic in the template to accomplish the same goal, without modifying context:

```
{{ category.first.name }}
```

You can preprocess objects when setting up your view's context and make them formatted the way you wish, or use Jinja in the template - both work and can be used in conjunction.

Comment: With category.first.name (I used .title) it shows the title of the main parent node now. I think this leads always to the first node of all the categories right? 
But I want to pick out one (sub)category and display, besides all products of that category, the name of the category.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I added cat = Category.objects.get(pk=id) in views, now i can call cat.title in the html.